# How to convert ext4 to bcachefs, on Linux Mint 21.x and LMDE6?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, ext4, bcachefs

**2023-10-31, Bcachefs Merged Into The Linux 6.7 Kernel:**

- https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7
- https://web.archive.org/web/20231103095158/https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7

**Manuals:**

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/bcachefs.8.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205131951/https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/bcachefs.8.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205131951/https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish

  The bcachefs management software bcachefs-tools are available by Application Management of Linux Mint 21 and actual Debian version, and consist follow related information:

  bcachefs migrate [options] device
  Migrate an existing filesystem to bcachefs

  ```
         -f fs   Root of filesystem to migrate

         --encrypted
                 Enable whole filesystem encryption (chacha20/poly1305)

         --no_passphrase
                 Don't encrypt master encryption key

         -F      Force, even if metadata file already exists
  ```

  bcachefs migrate-superblock [options] device
  Create default superblock after migrating

  ```
         -d device
                 Device to create superblock for

         -o offset
                 Offset of existing superblock
  ```

**Source:**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205130327/https://bcachefs.org/bcachefs-principles-of-operation.pdf

**Remark:**

I am looking for a answer now, which use the bcachefs-tools, gparted or comparable tools. The existing answer, to copy the data from old ext4 partition to a new bcachefs partition, are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Backup data on `ext4` filesystem you wish to convert. Then unmount the filesystem, use `bcachefs format` on the device containing the filesystem, edit `/etc/fstab` to reflect the fact that the filesystem type is now `bcachefs`, mount it, and restore the data.

Since the bcachefs filesystem is so new, there seems to be no published documentation for migration procedures yet. [The BcacheFS FAQ](https://bcachefs.org/FAQ/) has been last updated in 2017, but it says:

> If you wish to use bcachefs as a filesystem you will have to format the backing device (bdev/bcache) with the new filesystem.

Also, if you even consider using such a new filesystem as your root filesystem, you are more brave than me. Remember that as the bcachefs filesystem is only just merged to the main kernel, it's only just beginning to get significant large-scale testing outside the circle of people actively participating to its development.

Always keep your backups up to date. **Especially** when testing bleeding-edge filesystems.

Comment: I guess, the "becachefs-tools" offering a conversion... Setting quotas as well as creating partitions that do not take up the entire disk size can reduce the fear of full disks.

Comment: OK, so a migration tool seems to exist, but *documentation for migration procedure* seems to be not written yet. [The Bcachefs FAQ](https://bcachefs.org/FAQ) says: "If you wish to use bcachefs as a filesystem you will have to format the backing device (bdev/bcache) with the new filesystem." If you aren't already monitoring the [linux-bcache mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-bcache), you probably should do so - the most up-to-date information should be found there.

Comment: THX for the idea of mailing list. I checked now. Its looks for me, the http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-bcachefs  are the right one for bcachefs.

Comment: Oops, a copy/paste error, sorry.

Comment: But on the end, it was helping me. I didnt know the mailing list before. THX

Answer (score 0):

If you dont find a better way, you can change from ext4 to bcachefs filesystem  alternatively on follow two ways:

Variant 1:

- take a additional hard disk
- create a bcachefs filesystem on the new one
- copy the files from old hard disk to the new one, p.e. by:

  ```
  rsync -va -AHSX source target
  ```

Variant 2 (It can happen, you will lose your data on this way...):

- do a backup of your data
- delete the old filesystem
- create the new filesystem
- restore your data from backup

Answer (score 0):

You should consider it as migrating from one disk to another.
I.e. clone(dd) the root partition to another disk. Format the original one in bcachefs. And migrate from second one to the first one with files copying(cp -rxa).
There are many manuals(of disk migrating) how to do it better. I used [this one](https://losst.pro/perenos-linux-na-drugoj-disk) . If you can't read in Russian please use any webpage automatic translation tool.
The all difference of the manuals with your FS changing.

1. There are an intermediate disk. I.e. you have to copy the system files twice.
2. You are to change the filesystem type(ext4 -> bcachefs) as well as the disk partition(/dev/sda1) in the fstab file.
3. Make sure that you bcachefs driver is in your kernel before all. Create tiny bcachefs image file and mount it to your current system in boot time(fstab). Please don't run into FS driver missing with other answers if you choose them.

Sorry for little mess explanation. But in clear case I should write an article like mentioned above. Hope you'll happy with it.

Comment: It isnt asked by the Bounty for a answer like this. Please read the question: "Remark:

I am looking for a answer, which use the bcachefs-tools, gparted or comparable tools. The existing answer, to copy the data from old ext4 partition to a new bcachefs partition, are not what I am looking for."

Comment: @Eddy763 You are right! I've missed the point. But I don't see how to do it this way.  In common case 'anyfs-tools' is responsible for in-place FS converting, But I don't see 'bcachefs' in it's options.

Comment: The bcachefs-tools" offer about the follow (see the question): "bcachefs migrate [options] device Migrate an existing filesystem to bcachefs" But I dont know and didn test it. So a people a wanted, with a little bit experiance about this.

Comment: @Eddy763 yes, I see. There is an option from the tool. But as for me it is really riskful to use the option without a full backup. Also I would recommend you to create a filesystem in an image file and mount it on /dev/loopX to try how it works. If converting is ok, then boot on live DVD\USB with the tool and try to convert the whole system. Please don't forget the points #2 & #3 from my answer above. It is the steps you should complete after(2) & before(3) converting from Live DVD\USB on your converted system.

Comment: Its dosnt describe how to use the bcachefs-tools migrate option.

Comment: I agree. I can't describe it because haven't use the tool already. It is the job for 1-2 day to figure out the all details. I am not ready to do it for free, sorry. I made my note in case you have some ideas or other guys advise something to you. For my humble opinion these are the necessary steps anyway and you should know about them. Once upon a time I got these issues. I hope you will get around them.
You can ask any freelancer system administrator to check & describe all steps. But It should cost some money ~100-300$.

Answer (score 0):

**Converting ext4 to bcachefs are supported by:**

bcachefs-tools convert

**That can do on follow way:**

- Mount ext4 filesystem on a bcachefs supporting Linux
- convert the file system by bcachefs-tools convert
- unmount
- run migrate-superblock on the block device

**For details, see:**

- Manual: https://web.archive.org/web/20230205130327/https://bcachefs.org/bcachefs-principles-of-operation.pdf
- Samplecode:  https://web.archive.org/web/20230216084401/https://evilpiepirate.org/git/ktest.git/tree/tests/bcachefs/single_device.ktest

Comment: Can you add the commands from code example please to the answer?

Comment: Thats intresting, its looks like its support migration of xfs also.